# Creating a nested object

Tags: javascript, python, object, hashtable

this is what I am trying to do: `"book" => {b:{o:{o:k:{'end':true}`

can someone explain me / link me an explanation for this?

```
const ENDS_HERE = '__ENDS_HERE'

class Trie {
  constructor() {
    this.node = {};
  }
  insert(word){ 
    let trie = this.node;
    console.log( 'start inset', trie )
    for ( let index in word ) {
      let char = word[index];
      if ( !trie[char] ) {
        trie[char]= {}
      }
      console.log( trie )
      trie = trie[char]
    }
    trie[ENDS_HERE] = true
  }
}


let test= new Trie
test.insert('book')
test.insert('baak')
```

this is what it logs:

```
start inset {}
{ b: {} }
{ o: {} }
{ o: {} }
{ k: {} }
start inset { b: { o: { o: [Object] } } }
{ b: { o: { o: [Object] } } }
{ o: { o: { k: [Object] } }, a: {} }
{ a: {} }
{ k: {} }
```

on this line `trie = trie[char]` it reset the trie to `{}`.
the last line for insert function then set `{ '__ENDS_HERE' = true}`
however when calling `test.insert('baak')` you can see that `trie === { b: { o: { o: [Object] } } }` .

**my question is how does it build `{b:{o:{o:k:{'end':true}` ?**
same results occurs in python. above code is written in javascript.

Comment: I think the problem might be in this line: `for (let index in word)`. I believe index equals every character, instead of the character index. Try `for (let index = 0; index < word.length; i++)`?

Comment: that is true for python, in javascript it is a index

Comment: Your code looks like it's working fine. It makes a trie with book and baak. Is your question just why?

Answer (score 1):

A simpler solution constructing the *nested dictionary* from the inside out

```
s = 'book'
s = list(s)
s.append('end')
d = {}

for key in reversed(s):
    if key == 'end':
        d = {key: True}
    else:
        d = {key: d}
# {'b': {'o': {'o': {'k': {'end': True}}}}}
```

Comment: Not really what the question was asking. They are building a trie data structure not just a single nested object.

Comment: @MarkMeyer sorry just was looking at expected outcome, I can take this down

Answer (score 0):

try this function

```
insert(word) {
  const finalObj = {}; 
  let currentObj = finalObj;

  word.split('').forEach((char, i) => {
    if (i === 0) {
      finalObj[char] = {};
      currentObj = finalObj[char];
    } else {
      currentObj[char] = {};
      currentObj = currentObj[char];      
    }           
  });
  currentObj.end = true;
  return finalObj;
```

}